# How to build a nested group object in timevis

Tags: r, shiny, nested, grouping, vis.js

I am trying to use nested groups in timevis, which apparently are supported. However, there is no example and I am having difficulties to create a timevis object with nested groups.

The nested groups are defined within the groups object, but it is not clear how to add those as timevis requires groups to be a data.frame.

```r
library(timevis)
timevis(data = data.frame(
  start = c(Sys.Date(), Sys.Date(), Sys.Date() + 1, Sys.Date() + 2),
  content = c("one", "two", "three", "four"),
  group = c(1, 2, 3, 4)
  ),
  groups = data.frame(id = 1:4, content = c("G1", "G2","G3","G4"))
)
```

I would like G3 and G4 to be nested groups of G1. However, I am not sure how to build the groups object to define nestedGroups.